# Search DFM File using Delphi IDE

Tags: delphi

Is there a way within the Delphi to search within the dfm files for a string?

When I try the **Search->Find in Files** specifying **.dfm** it does not work.  However, if I change all the extensions from **dfm** to **txt** and specify **.txt** as the extension it works.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm using the [**GExperts grep**](http://www.gexperts.org/tour/grep_search.html) and it **works very well with dfm** when you check "Search Form Files"

[image]
<sub>(source: [gexperts.org](http://www.gexperts.org/tour/grep%20search.png))</sub>

**Update: why I prefer GExperts to D2010 "Find In Files"**...

- I work with **D2007** as well as **D2010**. I can use the **same search** tool **consistently** in both.
- You can limit your **search** to **Open/All-in-project/All-in-project-group** and still **get the dfm**, while in D2010 you get the dfm only for directories and it does not even work in D2007.
- **I can use both** if I want.

Comment: Delphi 2010's "Find in Files" can do that as well.

Comment: So, aside from using GExperts, Delphi 2010 does it but not Delphi 2007 (I should have mentioned I was using D2007)?

Comment: @M Schenkel. Yes, D2010 does it if you explicitly include *.dfm in the search mask, but not D2007.

Answer (score 3):

There is any easy way to work with DFM files.

- Open the form so you can see it
  visually.
- Right-click and select
  'View as Text'.
- Treat the resulting text file as source code, play with
  strings etc, then when you're done, right-click and select 'View as
  Form'.

  Try it.

Comment: You can also use ALT-F12 to switch between the form designer (but not the code view) and the form as text.

Comment: Yes - I was aware of that.  But what I really need to do is to search within all DFM in a directory or set of directories.

Comment: This doesn't work in recent versions of Delphi IDE, the form viewer overwrites any changes you make to the DFM file. What you can do however, is to use an external editor, such as Visual Studio Code, edit the DFM file there, then you just need to reopen the project to load the changes (this is very fast even for large projects) and behold, you have undo capabilities and can use your favorite editor!

Answer (score 2):

Ok... Not sure if you meant for a way to search from Delphi's IDE or from Windows.  From Delphi's IDE, like François mentionned, GExpert's GREP search does the job.  To allow Windows to read DFM/PAS files, you need to add a few registry key to allow it on Windows XP and later. Save the following content in a *.reg file and double-click on it to install in registry. (Note, that works in WinXP. I didn't try it in Win7/Vista)

Some of those keys might not be required... I just copied stuff from the `[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt]` key. ^_^

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.dfm]
"PerceivedType"="text"
"Content Type"="text/plain"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.dfm\PersistentHandler]
@="{5e941d80-bf96-11cd-b579-08002b30bfeb}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.pas]
"PerceivedType"="text"
"Content Type"="text/plain"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.pas\PersistentHandler]
@="{5e941d80-bf96-11cd-b579-08002b30bfeb}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response.  Yes - I meant to say "Within the Delphi IDE".